# How can I get lines where a specific word is repeated exactly N times?

Tags: text-processing

For this given input:

```
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
But not this line which is THIS word repeated 2 times.
And I will get This line with this here and This one
A test line with four this and This another THIS and last this
```

I want this output:

```
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
And I will get This line with this here and This one
```

Getting whole lines contains only three repeated "this" words. (case insensitive match)

Comment: To the too broad voter: how can a question possibly get more specific?

Comment: @JacobVlijm In that there are "too many possible answers". Pick `$RANDOM_LANGUAGE` - somebody will be able to come up with a solution in it.

Comment: @muru I would say the contrary, limiting it to one language would make it a *programming* (language) centred question. Now it is a *problem* centred question. There are maybe many possible solutions (languages), but not so many obvious ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `perl`, replace `this` with itself case-insensitively and count the number of replacements:

```
$ perl -ne 's/(this)/$1/ig == 3 && print' <<EOF
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
But not this line which is THIS word repeated 2 times.
And I will get This line with this here and This one
A test line with four this and This another THIS and last this
EOF
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
And I will get This line with this here and This one
```

Using [a count of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538542/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-inside-another-perl) instead:

```
perl -ne 'my $c = () = /this/ig; $c == 3 && print'
```

If you have GNU awk, a very simple way:

```
gawk -F'this' -v IGNORECASE=1 'NF == 4'
```

The number of fields will be one more than the number of separators.

Comment: Why replace? we can not count it directly without replace?

Comment: Indeed we can count, the code is slightly longer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538542/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-inside-another-perl

Comment: Upvote for the gawk command.

Answer (score 9):

In python, this would do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

s = """How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
But not this line which is THIS word repeated 2 times.
And I will get This line with this here and This one
A test line with four this and This another THIS and last this"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    if line.lower().count("this") == 3:
        print(line)
```

outputs:

```
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
And I will get This line with this here and This one
```

Or to read in from a file, with the file as argument:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file) as src:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in src.readlines()]

for line in lines:
    if line.lower().count("this") == 3:
        print(line)
```

- Paste the script into an empty file, save it as `find_3.py`, run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/find_3.py <file_withlines>
  ```

Of course the word "this" can be replaced by any other word (or other string or line section), and the number of occurrences per line can be set to any other value in the line:

```py
    if line.lower().count("this") == 3:
```

#### Edit

If the file would be large (hundreds of thousands / millions of lines), the code below would be faster; it reads the file per line instead of loading the file at once:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file) as src:
    for line in src:
        if line.lower().count("this") == 3:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: @KasiyA edited to use the file as argument.

Comment: Just curious: Why did you not use  a generator in the second code snippet?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your source file is tmp.txt,

```
grep -iv '.*this.*this.*this.*this' tmp.txt | grep -i '.*this.*this.*this.*'
```

The left grep outputs all lines that do not have 4 or more case-insensitive occurrences of "this" in tmp.txt.

The result is piped to the right grep, which outputs all lines with 3 or more occurrences in the left grep result.

Update: Thanks to @Muru, here is the better version of this solution,

```
grep -Eiv '(.*this){4,}' tmp.txt | grep -Ei '(.*this){3}'
```

replace 4 with n+1 and 3 with n.

Comment: This would fail for N > 4. And the first `grep` needs to end in `*`.

Comment: I mean you cannot write this for N = 50. And the question is for exactly three so you need another grep which discards all outputs containing less than or equal to two `this`. `grep -iv '.*this.*this.*this.*this.*' tmp.txt | grep -i '.*this.*this.*this.* |grep -iv '.*this.*this.'`

Comment: @prakharsingh95 It didn't fail for n > 4 and * is not required in first grep.

Comment: My bad. * not needed in first grep. But you cannot write this for N=50, and you need the third grep.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Yes, I agree it's not practical for something like n = 50, but it is a quick, one command solution for simple requirements. And look at the logic - the left grep excludes all 3+ occurrences and the grep on that result takes 3+ occurrences which naturally excludes the 2 occurrences.

Comment: @KasiyA what's your take on my answer?

Comment: @Sri ok, I was reading on tablet in a hurry, and indeed, two greps would work, but the time and code complexity issues remain :P

Comment: Simplify it a bit: `grep -Eiv '(.*this){4,}' | grep -Ei '(.*this){3}'` - this might make it practical for N=50.

Answer (score 6):

You can play a bit with `awk` for this:

```
awk -F"this" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} NF==4' file
```

This returns:

```
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
And I will get This line with this here and This one
```

#### Explanation

- What we do is to define the field separator to `this` itself. This way, the line will have as many fields +1 as times the word `this` appears.
- To make it case insensitive, we use `IGNORECASE = 1`. See reference: [Case Sensitivity in Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html).
- Then, it is just a matter of saying `NF==4` to get all those lines having `this` exactly three times. No more code is needed, since `{print $0}` (that is, print the current line) is the default behaviour of `awk` when an expression evaluates to `True`.

Comment: [Already posted](http://askubuntu.com/a/568832/158442), but good explanation.

Comment: @muru oh, I didn't see it! My apologies and +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the lines are stored in a file named `FILE`:

```bsh
while read line; do 
    if [ $(grep -oi "this" <<< "$line" | wc -w)  = 3 ]; then 
        echo "$line"; 
    fi  
done  <FILE
```

Comment: Thank you, you can remove your `sed ...` command and add `-o` option for `grep -oi ...` instead.

Comment: Simpler: `$(grep -ic "this" <<<"$line")`

Comment: @muru No, `-c` option will count number of *lines* that matched with "this" not number of "this" words in each line.

Comment: @KasiyA Ah, yes. My bad.

Comment: @KasiyA, wouldn't `-l` and `-w` be equivalent in this case?

Comment: In this case YES they are equal because we used `-o` option for grep and this cause each matched "this" words prints in separate newlines and with `-l` you just counting the number of newlines but it's good to use `-w` option to count words instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in Vim:

```
g/./if len(split(getline('.'), 'this\c', 1)) == 4 | print | endif
```

This will just print matched lines.

Comment: Nice example to search for lines with n occurrences of word, when using Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby one-liner solution:

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_ if $_.chomp.downcase.scan(/this/).count == 3' < input.txt                                    
How to get This line that this word repeated 3 times in THIS line?
And I will get This line with this here and This one
```

Works in a quite simple fashion: we redirect file into ruby's stdin, ruby gets line from stdin, cleans it up with `chomp` and `downcase`, and `scan().count` gives us number of occurrences of a substring.